How to answer the interview question why I am not working at my previous job?
I had a great job for over a year. I received positive references from management when I was laid off. After being unemployed for about a month, I started a new job that turned out to be an extremely poor fit. I found the environment to be very disorganized and toxic. I was there for approximately 3-4 months. The end of that position was strange, the company initiated the separation, but they provided severance on the condition that I sign an NDA and waiver not to pursue legal action. At the time, I was still within my six-month probation period. There was no specific incidences that I was aware that led to this, but I suspect management found out that I was looking for another job and didn't like this one. Also I was under a lot of stress around the time the job started. Someone close to me was very ill. Management was not understanding and did not want me to take time off or leave early etc.
When I'm interview for a job now, what should I say when they ask me how my old job ended? I was considering leaving this off my resume but feel that 3-4 months is a bit of a big gap.

why is the truth (within the limits of your nda, much the sort of things you've said here) not an option? What are you concerned about?

Saying you are honoring an NDA would actually have a lot of benefits here, and reassure them you'll honor their NDA.  Also, if you were laid off and not fired, that's a great talking point too!

"because I left" :-)

From what you have written, there are a number of options on how to address this

Sudden change in personal circumstances meant it was no longer a good fit (as you said - someone close to you was Ill)
You are under an NDA and cannot discuss it
It was not the right role or environment for you

I could go on - people often have a hang-up about saying that a particular job just did not work for them - and I disagree with this notion - there is no shame or harm in saying that you and the company were mismatched.
For example - a company might be in a start-up type phase and so will want someone comfortable with more responsibilities than they otherwise might expect, but without the bonus of additional pay.
There is a type of individual that will relish such an opportunity - trading on either a bigger salary when the company makes it big or that the additional responsibilities will pay dividends on a resume later.
Other people, however, are not good in this environment...
And there is no Shame in saying that you and the company were not a good fit
So long as the reasons are objective and impersonal - no one is going to look down at you.

It is okay to say "It wasn't a great fit"
If you don't have a history of short term employment, it is not a problem for most employers.

And the ones that don't like 1-2 short term jobs (generally speaking) do not have healthy work environments.

